# Android autolink links always start browser

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application with an activity dedicated to a webview. I also have a chat section of the app that autolinks web links in the messages. I've created a onItemClick listener on the chat messages to start the webview activity. This listener works when I click the whole chat bubble, but I noticed that if I only click the highlighted link in the message, the listener isn't called and instead my default browser is loaded up.

I put a log message in front of every instance of an intent with ACTION_VIEW, thinking that some other part of my app may be launching the browser, but it doesn't seem like this is the case.

I'm wondering if android has any default methods that catch autolink urls and starts the browser that I could override. Otherwise, I was thinking that I could turn off autolink and imitate the appearance of links with the blue text and the underline, but this seems like a poor solution.

Thanks ahead for any tips on how Android works!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this situation too, where I have `autolink` set up in TextViews to automatically handle URLs in TextViews. However, the default behavior is to open the web page in an external browser, so how do we make it open in a webview activity (for example)?

Beneath the hood, this is handled for TextView by [LinkMovementMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java). However, the behavior is difficult to customize. There is a 3rd party enhancement over LinkMovementMethod, known as [BetterLinkMovementMethod](https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method), described in more detail in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Saketme/a-better-way-to-handle-links-in-textview-27bb70b2d31c). With just a few lines of code changes, the TextView `autolinks` can be made to open in your webview activity (and clearly, all kinds of other behaviors can be customized as desired).